# Is there an efficient way to convert from Bundle to ContentValues?

Tags: android, bundle

The Bundle and ContentValues classes seem to have pretty similar functionality.

Is there an efficient way of converting from one to another (and vice-versa) without having to loop through the classes, calling get and put subsequently on each element?

Comment: I don't think any. You need to loop through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've scanned the Android source code and both Classes use a `Map` to hold the underlying data. Specifically, `Bundle` uses a `Map` and ContentValues uses a `HashMap`.

However, `Bundle` permits any parcelable objects to be loaded, while `ContentValues`' implementation accepts the primitive type classes (`Integer, String, Double` etc.) and byte arrays.

So it looks like in principle, `ContentValues` is a special case of `Bundle`, so converting  from `ContentValues` to `Bundle` might have been possible if the internals were accessible, but the reverse is problematic, since a `Bundle` can hold objects not strictly compatible with `ContentValues`.

Any comments on this are welcome.

Comment: Someone brought up a similar point in the early days of Android (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=463) concerning the similarities of the two. I'm still not sure why they both exist but I guess at this point we'll just have to deal with it.